# equation $7x^2-(k+13)x +k^2-k-2=0$. To find the range values of $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, roots, quadratics

The quadratic equation $7x^2-(k+13)x+k^2-k-2=0$, where $k$ is a constant, has two distinct real roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Given that $0<\alpha<1$ and $1<\beta<2,$ find the range of values of k.

I got $−2.055<k<4.055,$ but is unable to link to the alpha and beta.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I get $-2.055<k<4.055$, but is unable to link to the alpha and beta.

Comment: @puahkh I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please how you got this answer.

Comment: $b^2-4ac>0,
(k+13)^2-4(7)(k^2-k-2)>0, 
k^2+26k+196-28k^2+28k+56>0,
27k^2-54k-225>0,
3k^2-6k-25>0$

Comment: @puahkh OK. I posted. See now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)= 7x^2-(k+13)x+k^2-k-2.$

Now, solve the following system.
$$f(0)>0,$$ $$f(1)<0$$ and $$f(2)>0,$$ which is
$$k^2-k-2>0$$
$$k^2-2k-8<0$$ and
$$k^2-3k>0$$
Can you end it now?

I got $$(-2,-1)\cup(3,4)$$

Answer (score 1):

$7x^2-(k+13)x+k^2-k-2 = 0$
$\alpha, \beta \in x$

$0 < \alpha < 1$, $\alpha$ is $0→1$

$1 < \beta < 2$, $\beta$ is $1 → 2$

From this we can see than $\beta > \alpha$

Since $x$ is distinct and real, therefore it's discriminate $\delta$ is greater than $0$, $ \delta > 0$

$(k+13)^2 - 4\cdot{7}\cdot(k^2-k-2) > 0$

$k^2+2\cdot{13}\cdot{k}+13^2-28\cdot{k^2}+28\cdot{k}+28\cdot{2} > 0$

$-27k^2+54k+225 > 0$  $-3k^2+6k+25 > 0$

$3k^2-6k-25 < 0$

$\frac{3-\sqrt{84}}{3} < k < \frac{3+\sqrt{84}}{3}$

We know that discriminate, $\delta = (\alpha-\beta)^2$

Since $x$ is positive
$(\beta-\alpha)^2 > 0$, $\beta - \alpha > 0$

But $\alpha + \beta = \frac{k+13}{7}$

$\beta > \frac{k+13}{7*2}$ and $\alpha < \frac{k+13}{7*2}$

I'll better write it as

$\alpha < \frac{k+13}{14} < \beta$